# The file_name and raw_name came same in codeigniter , why?

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload, filenames, tmp

I uploaded the file using codeigniter library "upload" and returned the file_name from method `data()` , but the `file_name` is the `tmp_name` i don't know why?

any help

Comment: file_name=The name of the file that was uploaded including the file extension. Then what do you want??

Comment: the file name came out to be raw_name , have you used codeigniter?

Comment: my comment was based on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html  .. And about using codeigniter?? i do use. and if i am ready to help you u shouldn't care about what i use or don't ask for others help.

Comment: i got your point , i just have a simple question , and it can unly be answered when you know the data() function in `upload` library of codeigniter.

Comment: Do i edit my question and put some code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Please do it. filename is the name of the file with extension but raw name is only filename without extension.

Comment: no, in codeigniter rawname is the tmp_name it comes something like this `adbGHjnskjdhnk1213mbxcbkdsl`

Comment: So what do you want exactly?

Comment: simply, i just want the name to come as name not as rawname